# Using C Readline to read a line from file instead of stdin

Tags: c, file, stdin, readline

I'm using the readline from gcc -lreadline for reading from stdin. Later, I want to read from a file, so I tried the following, but it still paused for and accepted input from command prompt instead of accepting it from the file. Is there a fix for this approach?

```
FILE* savedStdin = stdin;
stdin = fopen("someFile.txt", "r");
char* input = readline(NULL);
stdin = savedStdin;
```

Comment: Okay, amuse us. *Why* do you want readline to read from a file?

Comment: Reading a line from a file is a very common task. However I've never seen someone try to redirect stdin and use `readline` to do it. Just fopen the file, and use fgets. `readline` is for *interactive* input.

Comment: The professor recommended we used readline for our project. Also, it is handy since it just works you don't have to allocate a max buffer size and have error code if it is over that, so you always get the line.

Comment: if your environment supports it, try using `getline` (standard as of POSIX1.2008) for file input. It (can) deal with the memory allocation all by itself - the man page has a good example.

Comment: I'm trying to go with getline for now. It seems that solves all my problems, since I can give it size_t = 0 and I don't need to manage it. I don't suppose I can accept a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The readline library is actually pretty flexible and can almost certainly be tortured to do what you want.  But it doesn't seem to make any sense to bother with that, when your stated reason for trying to use readline to read from a file (in a program which elsewhere uses readline to read from the console) is that you don't want to manage your input buffers yourself.  Just use readline to read console input (like a command prompt), and when you need to read from a file, do it the way you normally would without readline, such as by using `fgets()`.

If you really don't like all that, there's a global variable called `rl_instream` which you can modify to make readline read from a stream other than stdin.  Its type is `FILE*` and it is documented here:
https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how to modify a global variable inside a function I'm calling, so I am using getline which is working well so far.

Comment: The link above is broken but this one does document rl_instream: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_28.html

Comment: @PaulRubel: Thanks, I fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

maybe just try to use stdin, and run it using:

```
cat file.txt > program
```

Comment: This would normally work probably, but I'm making a shell, so I have to be able load shell scripts that load other shell scripts, so I have do it all in code.