# Readline (libedit) non-stdin input

Tags: c, autocomplete, lua, readline

I trying to make autocomplete and history functions for in-game lua console. I was proposed to use readline library (its BSD analog libedit, to be precise, but it has similar apis and rl-code builds with slightly headers changes), with lua bindings for what I choosed [lua-rlcompleter with history patches](https://github.com/SirAnthony/lua-rlcompleter). History works well, but i have some problems with readline function. For autocompletion I need to pass lua string to readline function, but this function in defaults reads from stdin. I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767774) in changing rl_instream to FILE*. For this purposes I creating tmpfile and writing to it. But it works strange, readline returns nothing when reading string this way.

```
// This definitions is just example, not working code 
// it shows the environment
static FILE *tempfile = tmpfile();
rl_instream = tempfile;
rl_initialize();

static int lreadline(lua_State *L)
{
  const char *prompt = lua_tostring(L, 1);
  char *line;
  if(rl_instream == NULL)
     // In case we using stdin
     line = readline(prompt);
  else{
      fputs(prompt, tempfile);
      /* maybe I need a fseek here? It not helps though.
       * fseek(tempfile, -strlen(prompt), SEEK_CUR);
       */
      line = readline(NULL);
  }
  lua_pushstring(L, line);
  free(line);
  return 1;
}
```

I'm not sure what is going on, but think it may be somehow related to reading position in file of readline function. I tried to read sources of libedit, but it not makes sense why my code not works as I expected. I was not able to debug this due to problems with debugging of shared libraries with eclipse, but planning to use pure gdb, not sure it will helps.

Also, maybe I'm doing it wrong and there is another simple way to autocomplete and history in lua-based console emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to have trouble with `libedit`, take a look at [`linenoise`](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise/)